# Requests per second between a Web Browser vs a Web Scrapper

Tags: internet, browser, web

My understanding:
When a Web Browser makes a request to view a page, the server responds back with the HTML.  Then the Web Browser renders that HTML code, it sends requests for each Embedded Object (such as images) it sees in the HTML to the server in less than a second (give or take).  However, using a Web Scrapper I make a request to the server grabbing only the HTML and not rendering the HTML at all.

Proper etiquette for Web Scrapping says that you should limit your requests to one per second at a maximum to not overload the server.

So, why is it not a problem when the Web Browser sends a request for each Embedded Object (multiple requests withing a second), but it is for a Web Scrapper to send multiple requests a second, just for the HTML source for different pages?

Answer (score 1):

The reasons web scrapers (not scrappers) use a delay are:

- to hide that they are scraping the web and be banned from sites they are trying to scrape (by using slight delays between pages, they look more like a web browser operated by a human being, who is surfing the net)
- out of courtesy towards the owner of the website (requesting a lot of data in a very short period of time could overload the server and make the site seem unresponsive for other users of the site)

When your browser (or a web scraper) requests a page, it doesn't have to wait a full second between requesting objects on the same page. It can request them immediately - this results in a better user experience (faster page loads).

What a 'normal' user won't do is to request different pages within a very short period of time. A user will look at a page, click on a link to get to the next page, etc.
Therefore, when a user is browsing a site, there will be a delay between requesting different pages from the same website. This is very likely the 1 second delay you mentioned in your question.

Obviously, to scrape a site quickly, web scrapers will want to use the shortest delay possible. They will use different ways to speed up the process (e.g. scrape multiple sites in parallel; make it look as if the requests are from multiple different users).
For web scrapers, there will always a trade-off between the reasons for having a delay and the necessity to get the job done.

For more information, see the entry on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)

Comment: Basically, even if a human's web browser can request more quickly, there are delays as the human digests the content. So there are spikes of traffic as the new page or content is loaded, and then lulls as the human reads or watches. With a scraper, there is the potential for a constant, hard drain on the server because the scraper does not need to digest the content, only store it.